# Is it really not advisable to edit the height and width of the <li>?

Tags: html, css

I have a mentor that told me that instead of editing the height or width of the "li" tag that I should just edit the padding or margin of its content like lets say the "a" tag or "p" tag until i reached the desired size. Is it true? is it really not advisable? Thank you in advance that can clear this one up.

Comment: That kind of depends on what the `<li>` is being used for. How about you post a full example?

Comment: http://i168.photobucket.com/albums/u173/carlocarr/example_zps9e254f10.jpg  heres the screenshot of what im trying to achieve. The nav menu has this big box around the link. should i just edit the "li" tag or just adjust the padding or edit the height of "a" tag instead?? whats more advisable? or it doesnt matter if i edit the "li" or the "a" tag.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at that picture, I think they meant two things:

- You must make sure that the clickable area (the size of the `a` element) is the same as the area that look clickable. If your `li` element has a background color but the `a` element inside doesn't cover it completely, it's really annoying because you have visible areas that aren't clickable.
- If you use padding, the items will adjust their size depending on the text size, e.g. if somebody decides to put in more text or the font size changes, the element height will adjust accordingly.

Comment: well actually i just want the text to be the one clickable. so does it mean im doing it right?? cause in that example i edit the height and width of the li and not of the a tag.

Comment: @Carlo: Why can't I click the entire area, why do I have to aim for the text?

Comment: just downloaded this psd somewhere and as per the finished site of the psd. only the text is clickable so im just copying it. :)

Comment: @Carlo: Yeah, of course, if you don't want to aspire to be good and are OK with a mediocre result, go on ahead.

Comment: huh? i know how to make the whole box clickable its just that the design doesnt ask for it to be clickable. Im just asking if its ok to edit the height or width of the "li" tag.